# Is it possible to create Django passwords with Perl?

Tags: python, django, perl, sha

So an emergency project was dumped on me to merge a MySQL user database into an existing Django user database.

I've figured just about everything out except how to handle the passwords as they use different hashes. I don't know Python, the Django backend, or very much about hashing techniques.

I do have a way to verify users with their emails, I just need a way to take the passwords they give me and save them into the database in a Django-acceptable way.  It will be have to be done in Perl since that's the only language I know on the server.

I found [this page](http://www.bloggerpolis.com/2011/09/how-to-generate-a-django-password/) talking about how Django handles passwords, but I sadly don't understand most of what they're saying.  Also, I don't know if it's any help, but the admin area of the Django site gives the "hint" of

> "Use '[algo]$[salt]$[hexdigest]'" for the password.

That doesn't mean much to me either, but maybe it does to one of you?

Comment: Do you have the salt the passwords hash was created with?

Comment: I have access to all the python scripts that power Django, so if someone can tell me what file I need to look in, I can get it.

Comment: what is the algorithm for the existing Django users?  (the part before the first $)

Comment: it sounds like you have the existing MySQL user database passwords in cleartext, not hashed?  can you confirm that?

Comment: @ysth, the algorithm I believe is the one I [linked to in the post](http://www.bloggerpolis.com/2011/09/how-to-generate-a-django-password/).  And the MySQL is user passwords are hashed differently, so I just can't copy them over.  Users will have to choose new passwords with a perl script that I'm writing, but I just don't know how to take the passwords they give me and encrypt them for the database.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the algorithm is configurable, which is why I suggested looking at what the existing Django users have.

Comment: Ok… does this help… here's the encrypted password of my own account on the site - sha1$a35f0$9bd1c45156c545041c91222bb4658e88d6cbfb63

Comment: Well it does help at least in that we now know that the passwords are three part and using sha1. So either do what is suggested in the answer given or re-write the salt part for perl Is that the part that you need help with?

Comment: Yes… rewriting the salt for Perl.  I've only done hashing I've done is the [PHP crypt](http://us1.php.net/crypt) which just takes the function, the password string, and the salt string.  This looks like it's more complex than that.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to handle this: convert existing passwords to a format acceptable by Django, or write your own Django password hasher.

For the first way, as you found, the password field consists of three parts, each separated by a `$`. (Django 1.6 passwords *may* have 4 parts, but let's ignore that extra part for now, since Django 1.6 also supports the more traditional 3-part passwords.) The parts are

- **algorithm,** which describes the password hashing algorithm; it will look like *md5*, *pbkdf2*, etc.
- **salt,** the salt for the hash algorithm
- **hexdigest,** the hashed password

So, assuming your passwords are already salted and hashed, your script needs to take the hashed/salted passwords in your existing database, separate the salt from the hash, then store them into the database with the appropriate algorithm string prefixed. There should be Perl modules for doing password hashing using various algorithms. Django's recommended algorithm is PBKDF2. bcrypt is also good. Any hash algorithm is fine, though, as far as Django is concerned, as long as it has a built-in hasher for that algorithm (Django has hashers for the most common hashing algorithms).

If your existing passwords are not salted and hashed…well, now would be a good time to do that. ;-)

---

The alternative way is to just copy the passwords over to the new database as-is, and write your own [password hasher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/) to handle them in your Django app. Of course, that would require writing some Python code.

Comment: So if the algorithm is sha1, is that enough to write a perl script that takes an unencrypted password and convert it to something Django would use?  We're still on like Django 0.8 because the company is (rightly so) afraid upgrading will break something and we don't have anyone who knows Django.

Comment: writing a new password hasher didn't sound like an option, since it sounds like they have existing Django users as well as those they are adding.

Comment: As @ysth said, there are already users in the database that I'm merging the new ones with.  We've accepted the fact that the MySQL users will have to choose new/re-enter passwords the next time they want to log in.  All I'm trying to do is email them unique links (to confirm each user), and then on that link, have them choose a new password and add it to the database in a format that Django will recognize when they try to log in that way.  I'm not sure how the salt works… looking through the list of salts already in the database, it's always 5 hex characters, some are the same, most are unique

Comment: salt is a random number, ideally chosen for each new password, that is added into the data so that the same password doesn't always hash the same way (which makes lookup tables trivial to construct for common passwords)

Comment: Someone in a different forum just suggested using the built-in password reset.  It's a little bit of a hassle, but it's a lot less coding, and it would work.  So I think that's the way I'm going to go.  And thanks for the salt explanation.  In my other projects, I just use the username for the salt, as it makes each one unique… and no need to store the salt in the password field.

Comment: @ysth: A Django project can have multiple password hashers.